# Происхождение слова "апельсин"

Tags: этимология

Ни в одном языке апельсин так не называется. В России апельсины не растут, значит, собственного названия иметь не могли. Откуда же произошло это слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда апельсины впервые появились в России, их по привычке называли яблоками. Продавали их голландцы, и, когда покупатели спрашивали, откуда эти "яблоки", те отвечали: из Китая. По голландски "яблоко" - appel, Китая - Sien. Вместе - "апельсин".

Answer (score 4):

> Ни в одном языке апельсин так не называется. В России апельсины не
>   растут, значит, собственного названия иметь не могли. Откуда же
>   произошло это слово?

Ну почему "ни в одном"?  В голландском есть. Из него во многие языки попало. 
Да и в немецком есть во многих диалектах.

> Когда апельсины впервые появились в России, их по привычке называли
>   яблоками. Продавали их голландцы, и, когда покупатели спрашивали,
>   откуда эти "яблоки", те отвечали: из Китая. По голландски "яблоко" -
>   appel, Китая - Sien. Вместе - "апельсин".

Не совсем так. Никто никому не отвечал так глупо. В голландском и так есть слово appelsien (переиначенное от sinaasappel) - означает "китайское яблоко".

Answer (score 1):

Апельсин от appelsien - из брабантского диалекта нидерландского языка (на нём говорят на территории Фландрии на юге Нидерландов и севере Бельгии). В нидерландских словарях данная форма помечена как региональная калька с французского pomme de Sine (китайское яблоко), в современном литературном нидерландском корректным названием является sinaasappel.

Answer (score -3):

А я думаю, что это слово было заимствовано из английского apple и sin яблоко и грех, греховное яблоко :-)

Comment: А как-нибудь подтвердить эту версию можете?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?